# how to use uiautomator commands in eclipse without deprecated

Tags: eclipse, android-uiautomator

I want to use a few uiautomator commands to click on a resource id in Eclipse, but it is showing them as deprecated. Is there any way without depreciation I can use these command in Eclipse without using in Android Studio?

Comment: Code is deprecated for a **reason**, try and see if you can find alternative methods of achieving your goal without using the deprecated methods.

Comment: Is there any other tool to click on a resource id except Uiautomator and Appium ?

Comment: Try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)